# Embed username & password in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, credentials

I have created an Excel sheet that fetches data from our SQL server via Power Query. Works great when I use it.

I would like to send this to a colleague so he can refresh and see data whenever he needs it, instead of me having to supply it to him every time.

He does not have access to the SQL server, but I have created a specific read-only user on the SQL server and would like to embed the username and password into Excel so data would be fetched using this.

I have Googled around for a solution, but a few times it just ended up with the "can't be done" answer.

Can this really be true? Even when I specifically use a **read-only** user, so there is no danger of the colleague starting to mess up the data?

Embedding credentials is standard procedure in the Tableau dashboards we create, so I would be very surprised if this feature is totally inaccessible in Excel?

Any input is appreciated, and alternatives for a solution would also be great.

Comment: [Manage data source settings and permissions (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-data-source-settings-and-permissions-power-query-9f24a631-f7eb-4729-88dd-6a4921380ca9)

Comment: We also face this issue at work. Alternatives we have used 1) set up a Domain Group with the appropriate access and add the user to that group  2) Grant the individual user the appropriate access with Windows Authentication 3) Set up a "shared" account with the appropriate  access and remote onto individual users PCs to enter the password details when required. ODC files are not an option for us (policy)